# Security of the server's private key

Tags: elliptic-curves, identity-based-encryption

In some papers, 
server generates keys for users as follows:
$$sk_i=msk+H(ID_i)v_i\ (mod \ p)$$ 
where $msk=$ the secret key of server

$v_i$ is randomly selected from $Z_p$ for i-th user , $p$ is a prime number

$ID_i=$ the identity of i-th user

$sk_i=$ the secret key for i-thuser

$H$ is the hash function

If there is a user who knows more than one secret key, does that key generation scheme prevent to reveal the value of $msk$ from users.

How to prove the security?

I have forgotten paper references. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can we assume that $v$ and $p$ are generated once for the server? Please explain how they are used in the protocol. You've specified the algorithm, which is great, but I'm missing the context and time factor.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes. $v$ is uniformly randomly selected for each users. Therefore, we can assume $v_i$ for i-th user. $p$ is generated once for the server.

Comment: Do the users learn their $v_i$ directly at any point or are they just being given their $sk_i$?

Comment: @SEJPM. No, server gives $v_iP$ and $sk_i$ to user.  Users do not learn $v_i$ directly.

Answer (score 2):

Not really worked with these kinds of schemes, but here's my viewpoint.

Write $w_i=H(ID_i)v_i$. The value $H(ID_i)$ is some fixed public value, so we can kind of forget about it. That is, if $v_i$ is uniformly random, then so is $w_i$.

Now the key is generated as $sk_i=msk+w_i\pmod{p}$. Since $w_i$ is uniformly random, this is simply a generalisation of the one-time pad. In other words, $sk_i$ reveals no information whatsoever about $msk$. Therefore however many times you repeat this, the user will still learn nothing about $msk$.

Comment: This is a good answer considering the information about the problem that is given and assuming that when the user gets $v_iP$ the $v_i$ is protected by DLOG.